# Deleted contacts considered duplicate in mailing

Tags: mailing, deleted

Some weeks ago clients reported problems of mass mailings not being delivered to a part of the destinees. After doing some research it occurred that the problem lied in contacts that had been merged.

When contact A is merged in contact B, contact A gets deleted (still in the database but status 'is_deleted'). When creating a mailing both A and B seem to be added to the destinees.

When sending the mailing contact A obviously doesn't receive the mailing because 'is_deleted' but contact B also doesn't get the mailing because the mail is regarded as a duplicate mail.

After some looking around I found https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/48b1ff58 which solved the issue for us on multiple installs.

Now I hoped this would quickly find its way into the releases, but when I just took a look at the freshly released 5.34.0 it clearly hasn't.

The error is so obious though that I feel I must be missing something myself, so I hesitate to file a bug report...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release process means it takes a while from a PR being merged until it appears in a release.  You can find details of the process [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/release-process/).  The commit you mentioned will be in 5.35

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand though I am still surprised this is not a huge problem for a lot people.

Comment: Is there actually a way to detect in which branch a pull request or patch will get implemented?